# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell get_Item(Int32)' method

Tags: linq, entities

Hi im too new on entity framework and im using it on windows form app.

```
            using (GezentiEntities GE = new GezentiEntities())
        {
            var cities = from c in GE.Cities
                         where c.CountryId == ((Guid)(dgCountry.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value))
                         select new  { c.Id, Şehir = c.Name };
            dgCity.DataSource = cities.ToList();

        }
```

on  dgCity.DataSource = cities.ToList(); line  it gives me error when im using it with where condition and ((Guid)(dgCountry.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value)) that code works fine it gives me ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to get the needed ID out of the linq to entities query

```
var id = (Guid)dgCountry.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
var cities = from c in GE.Cities
                         where c.CountryId == id
                         select new  { c.Id, Şehir = c.Name };
            dgCity.DataSource = cities.ToList();
```